# Can MongoDb return result of increment?

Tags: mongodb

Is is possible to do a MongoDB increment ($inc) and return the result of the increment as part of the same call, rather than having to make two calls?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will have to use [findandModify()](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/#db-collection-findandmodify).

From the docs:

> Modifies and returns a single document. By default, the returned document does not include the modifications made on the update. To return the document with the modifications made on the update, use the new option. The findAndModify() method is a shell helper around the findAndModify command.

You can use as such:

```
db.yourCollection.findAndModify({
  query:{},
  update: { $inc: { propertyToIncrement: 1 }},
  new: true
})
```

Comment: I would like to add to this answer that findAndModify will by default return the document *before* the modification. To get the document *after* the modification with the new update, add `new:true`.

Comment: oh, and you are also missing an opening `{`.

Comment: To save future commenters the trouble, the `{` is no longer missing.